# Prove an inequality on natural number

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory, inequality, exponentiation

Show that if $ a,b\in N$ and $a < b$, 
then $$\frac{a^a}{(a+1)^{a+1}} > \frac{b^b}{(b+1)^{b+1}}.$$

Comment: It would be better to show on the positive reals.

Comment: @peterh: It can be proven on $\mathbb{R}^+$ using calculus, or on $\mathbb{N}$ using Bernoulli's Inequality, which only requires induction. Both have advantages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint.** You may just observe that, for $x >0$, the function given by $$f(x)=\log \left(\dfrac{x^x}{(x+1)^{x+1}} \right) $$ **is decreasing**. Indeed, we have
$$
f(x)=-x \log\left(1+\frac 1x\right)-\log (x+1)
$$ and
$$
f'(x)=- \log\left(1+\frac 1x\right)<0, \qquad x>0.
$$

Answer (score 9):

Using [Bernoulli's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(a+1)^{a+1}}{a^a}\frac{(a-1)^{a-1}}{a^a}
&=\frac{a+1}{a-1}\left(1-\frac1{a^2}\right)^a\\
&\ge\frac{a+1}{a-1}\left(1-\frac1a\right)\\
&=\frac{a+1}a\\[8pt]
&\gt1
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{a^a}{(a+1)^{a+1}}\lt\frac{(a-1)^{a-1}}{a^a}
$$
which says that $\dfrac{a^a}{(a+1)^{a+1}}$ is a strictly decreasing function of $a$.